# Why does Puppeteer elementHandler not have a selector argument?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Here is my code:

```
const $container = $('.container');
$container.on('click', '#btn', function(){});
```

How can I trigger my button's event?

Comment: Do you mean that the code you’ve given is on the webpage and you want to trigger the `click` event from Puppeteer?

Comment: @Aankhen yes. This code is already in my HTML, and I want to trigger it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I had forgotten this question.

```
await page.waitForSelector(INPUT_SELECTOR, {timeout: 15000});
const pointer = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
  const rect = document.querySelector(sel).getBoundingClientRect();
  return [(rect.top + rect.height) / 2, (rect.left + rect.width) / 2];
}, INPUT_SELECTOR);
await page.mouse.click(...pointer);
```

Just use the native mouse event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to accomplish your task:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.id === 'btn') {
      // Your function ...
    }
  });
});
```

Then you can test the result using [`page.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options):

```
await page.click('#btn');
```